# Why if I normally write on Google the letter "é" it works perfectly, but it doesn't work on Google docs? (Bluetooth Keyboard on Android Tablet)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, android, keyboard-layout, google-docs

I read a similar topic about the combo "Ctrl"+"alt"+ "M" that wasn't working for someone 'cause Google Docs has it's own keyboard combinations but i haven't managed to solve this thing.

I use a tablet and an external keyboard with an American layout(bluetooth) to write documents and pdf. The problem is that even if i use the right combination to obtain "é" ("alt+'+e", "alt+e+e" or simply "alt+e" that on other layouts is "altgr+ key" combination) it just works outside Google Docs. Even while i'm writing this question here i did it easily just pressing those 2 keys, while on Google Docs pressing "alt+'+e = 'e" or "alt+e+e= e", so it's not working.

It works everywhere except for Google Docs and i don't know how to solve it if not doing "é" letter outside, copying it and pasteing it where i need it in the Docs.
But it's really annoying.

I also tried to change languages and layout but nothing changed, i think it's a Docs internal thing...what can i do?

Comment: This option is a keyboard shortcut by the operating system. Are you on Windows? I don't see any difference with Alt+e between Google Docs and elsewhere.

Comment: I'm on Android, my bad I didn't specify it before, sorry

Answer (score 0):

This *can* depend on encoding/code-page/random layman term for character sets, but for winodws, you can try: (using the numpad) hold alt, type 0233, release alt. This should work system-wide.

For other potential combos, open the default windows program charmap.exe, find and click on the glyph, and in the lower right of the Charmap window you will see "Keystroke: Alt+{4-digit number left-padded with zero}

Comment: these glyphs sometimes are not cross-platform or cross-font, but the "latin/extended latin" ones usually are. IIRC, this is the same number as unicode and UTF-16 and html entity.